# Serilog How to ensure no duplicate sinks, filters or similar entries in the config?

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I would like to configure Serilog in the program code with predefined values, because we often have the same logging requirements. So that the default values can be changed, I want to configure Serilog with environment variables and command line parameters via the `IConfigurationBuilder`.

My problem is that I can't delete anything from the config object. That means if someone adds a sink that is already configured by default, it will exist twice.

Can I prevent this somehow? Do you have any ideas for me how to prevent duplicate entries in the resulting configuration?

Here is some example code, maybe for clarification:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog.Exceptions;

namespace example.Logging;

public static class LoggingConfigurator
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration CreateLoggerConfiguration(
         IConfiguration                         configuration,
         bool                                   useStandardConfig = true,
         Func<LoggerConfiguration, LoggerConfiguration> configure = null)
    {
        var     loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration();

        if (useStandardConfig)
        {
            // standard configuration
            loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Override("microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning);
            loggerConfiguration.Enrich.FromLogContext();
            loggerConfiguration.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails();

            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Async(
                a =>
                {
                    a.Debug();
                    a.Console();
                }
            );
        }

        if (configure is not null)
        {
            loggerConfiguration = configure(loggerConfiguration);
        }

        loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);

        return loggerConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `Serilog` has anything to do this for you, but you can validate the `IConfiguration` by reading it and ensuring there are no duplicates before you pass it to `Serilog`. You can do this by iterating the config children using `.GetChildren()`

Comment: @Kieran Devlin yeah thank you with that I could ensure that no double values come from files or so. but this NOT resolves the problem that I can not ensure that no double values in the configurationobject from Serilog (LoggerConfiguration)